# Understanding c++ regex by a simple example

Tags: c++, regex

I wrote the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    std::string str("1231");
    std::regex r("^(\\d)");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, r);
    for(auto v: m) std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0652e59b74536e94)**

and got confused by its behavior. If I understood the purpose of the `match_result` from [there](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/) correctly, the only one `1` should have been printed. Actually:

> If successful, it is not empty and contains a series of sub_match
>   objects: the **first sub_match element corresponds to the entire match,**
>   and, if the regex expression contained sub-expressions to be matched ([...])

The string passed to the function doesn't match the regex, therefore we should **not** have had `the entire match`.

What did I miss?

Comment: You still get the *entire match* but the *entire match* does not fit the *entire string* it fits the *entire regex*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You still get the *entire match* but the *entire match* does not fit the *entire string* it fits the *entire regex*.

For example consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string str("1231");
    std::regex r("^(\\d)\\d"); // entire match will be 2 numbers

    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, r);

    for(auto v: m)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
12
1
```

The *entire match* (first sub_match) is what the *entire regex* matches against (part of the string).

The second sub_match is the first (and only) *capture group*

Looking at your original *regex*

```
std::regex r("^(\\d)");
              |----| <- entire expression (sub_match #0)

std::regex r("^(\\d)");
               |---| <- first capture group (sub_match #1)
```

That is where the two *sub_matches* come from.

Comment: So shy did I get the same result [there](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f60dc6ddd65321de)? We have two 1 characters.

Comment: @DmitryBundin The first sub_match is the entire regex, the second sub_match is only the part of the regex that is in parens `(\\d)`. It just happens that you put the whole regex in parens.

Comment: Does the function search for the first match and stop it when it find one?

Comment: @DmitryBundin I added a diagram to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @DmitryBundin First it matches the whole expression and adds that to the *sub_matches*. Next it looks for *parens* `(...)` and adds any it finds to the *sub_matches*.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/)

```
    Returns whether **some** sub-sequence in the target sequence (the subject) 
    matches the regular expression rgx (the pattern). The target sequence is 
    either s or the character sequence between first and last, depending on 
    the version used.
```

So regex_search will search for anything in the input string that matches the regex. The whole string doesnt have to match, just part of it.

However, if you were to use regex_match, then the **entire** string must match.