# Checking for numbers that are bigger than one digit in a string

Tags: c++

What is the best way of walking down a string and finding two digit+ numbers and designating them as such.

How do you go from a string like this: "1+22"

to something where they are separated like: "1", "+", "22"

my thought is to put them into an array of strings but im unsure of how to walk down a string then try to find the numbers im looking for.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.  Look into `<algorithm>` for inspiration. 
 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/  Include a [MCVE] that we can cut/paste/compile.

Comment: First, you could start by opening your favorite text editor, and writing the code, that does it. SO is **not** a code writing service.

Comment: Start by googling "tokenizing and parsing"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match the digits and the operations, for example, something like this `std::regex r("([-+/*]|\d+)");` and use regex search to capture the digits and operations.

Check an example RegeX [Understanding c++ regex by a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921932/understanding-c-regex-by-a-simple-example)

Answer (score -2):

Try using a loop to iterate characters in the string, while maintaining the following state: (1) current segment of string, (2) whether the current segment consists of all digits.