# How can i use regex in my code to split string line that divided by comma

Tags: c++, regex

Hello i have text file has each line like below.

```
101,Tarkan,E,1,22,1,1,0             
102,Mustafa,E,2,54,0,0,1       
103,Seher,K,2,65,0,1,0      
104,Ali,E,1,88,0,1,0      
105,Ahmet,E,3,12,1,0,0      
106,Osman,E,5,2,0,0,0    
107,Remziye,K,3,63,0,0,1       
108,Ayse,K,1,10,0,0,0        
109,Esma,K,2,25,0,0,0       
110,Mahmut,E,1,35,0,0,0
```

Here is my code. I need to split and assign to related variables using regex with C++

```
string line;
string items[8];
int i=0,j=0;
if (!fkisiler)
    cout<<"kisiler.txt bulunamadi";
else{
    while (getline(fkisiler,line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        string item;
        while (getline(ss,item,',')){
            items[i]=item;
            cout<<items[i]<<"\t";
            i++;
        }
        kisiler[j].id=stoi(items[0]);
        kisiler[j].isim=items[1];
        kisiler[j].cinsiyet=items[2][0];
        kisiler[j].mahalle=stoi(items[3]);
        kisiler[j].yas=stoi(items[4]);
        kisiler[j].covid19=stoi(items[5]);
        kisiler[j].kronik=stoi(items[6]);
        kisiler[j].il_disi=stoi(items[7]);

        cout<<"\n*****\n";
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::regex`?

Comment: I don't know how to use

Comment: [Understanding c++ regex by a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921932/understanding-c-regex-by-a-simple-example/30922295)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure regex is better, but you might do:

```
const std::regex reg{R"(^(\d+),(\w+),(\w),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)$)"};

while (std::getline(fkisiler, line)){
    std::smatch items;
    if (std::regex_match(line, items, reg)) {

        kisiler[j].id = stoi(items[1]);
        kisiler[j].isim = items[2];
        kisiler[j].cinsiyet = items[3][0];
        kisiler[j].mahalle = stoi(items[4]);
        kisiler[j].yas = stoi(items[5]);
        kisiler[j].covid19 = stoi(items[6]);
        kisiler[j].kronik = stoi(items[7]);
        kisiler[j].il_disi = stoi(items[8]);

        std::cout << "\n*****\n";
        j++;
    } // else handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `split()` function to split a string with a delimiter that you choose. You can even choose another delimiter where `delimiter.length() > 1`, like `"><", ",.,"` ...etc

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& t, std::string delimiter)
 {
    char* p = &t.at(0);
    std::string result = "";
    std::vector<std::string> out = {};
    size_t sum;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t.length(); i++)
       {
           if  (*p != delimiter[0])
               {
                   result.push_back(*p);
                   p++;
                   sum = 1;
               }
           else
               {
                   char* d = &delimiter.at(0);
                   std::string s = "";
                   for(size_t j = 0; j < delimiter.length(); j++)
                       {
                           if(*p == *d)
                               {
                                   s.push_back(*p);
                                   d++;
                                   p++;
                                   sum = j+1;
                                   if (j > 0)
                                      ++i;
                               }
                           else 
                               {
                                   result +=s;
                                   break;
                               }
                       }
                   if (sum == (delimiter.length()))
                       {
                           out.push_back(result);
                           result="";
                       }
               } 
       }

   out.push_back(result); 
   return out;
}

void printed (std::vector<std::string> v)
    {
        for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

int main()
  {
     std::string text = "101,Tarkan,E,1,22,1,1,0";
     std::string delimter = ",";
     std::vector<std::string> out = {};

     out = split(text, delimter);
     printed(out);

     return 0;
 }
```